# How to set a foreign key to a default value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry if this is a repeat question, but the answers I found when I searched didn't make any sense. I'm trying to set the location foreign key to auto update to 1 (ie, unsorted) if a certain deck is deleted from the deck table. I don't want to cascade, otherwise it would delete all the cards' info that were held in that deck.

```
CREATE TABLE decks (
    deck_number INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    deck_name VARCHAR(40)
);
CREATE TABLE mtg_cards (
    multiverse_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    card_name VARCHAR (40),
    set_name VARCHAR (40),
    price DECIMAL (8,2),
    location INT DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY(location) REFERENCES decks(deck_number) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
);
--DECKS--
INSERT INTO decks VALUES(1,'Unsorted');
INSERT INTO decks VALUES(2,'Prifddinas Tribe');
INSERT INTO decks VALUES(3,'Bosh Smasshhhh!!!');
INSERT INTO decks VALUES(4,'Best Served Cold');

--CARDS---
INSERT INTO mtg_cards VALUES(420830,'Nath of the Gilt-Leaf','Commander 2016',NULL,2);

DELETE FROM decks
WHERE deck_name = 'Prifddinas Tribe';
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`.

Comment: If you want to keep the row, use `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Although MySQL "supports" `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`, it is rejected under the hood by most storage engines including InnoDB, A work around could be a Trigger which update all records referencing the deleted foreign key to 1, this means you set  `ON DELETE NO ACTION` for the foreign key constraint, something like this:
`CREATE TRIGGER TRG2 BEFORE DELETE ON decks  FOR EACH ROW UPDATE mtg_cards SET location = 1 WHERE location = OLD.deck_number;`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm just getting into SQL and coding in general, so I appreciate the help. I know I'll probably be back here soon...

Comment: @Tanchwa alright.
PS: triggers just listen for changes on a particular table and perform some action once the change is detected, in the case we are listening for any DELETE changes on the parent table(decks), once such a change is detected, we the get the id of the row being deleted(ID.deck_number) and update the foreign key (location) in all the records in the child table(mtg_cards)  which are referencing the deleted id